# Run code in a Proxy context

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-harmony

I'm experimenting with Harmony Proxies and I'd like to run code in a Proxy context, which means that the global object of the code will be a Proxy. For example, if I call the function foo() in the code, it will be managed by the proxy get() method.

But using Proxy.create() and vm.runInNewContext() doesn't work, it seems that the Proxy object is overwritten by a new context object and looses his properties.

```
var vm = require('vm');

var proxy = Proxy.create({
    get: function(a, name){
        return function(){
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    }
});

vm.runInNewContext("foo('bar')", proxy); // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

**// EDIT**

```
(function() {
    eval("this.foo('bar')");
}).call(proxy);
```

The above code works well, but I'd like to be able not to use the `this` statement, and directly refer to the global context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in two ways. In Node, I was able to do this with a slightly modified contextify. Contextify is a module that allows for turning arbitrary objects into global contexts to run similar to the vm module. It does this by creating a global object that has a named property interceptor which then forwards accesses to the object, so it's able to keep the reference "live" instead of copying the properties as node's builtin vm does. The modification I made was to change it so that these accesses would trigger the correct proxy traps, IE changing `ctx->sandbox->GetRealNamedProperty(property)` (which doesn't trigger proxy get trap) to `ctx->sandbox->Get(property)`. Similar changes for has, set, etc. Property enumeration doesn't work quite right (nor does it in contextify normally) because the ability to hand the property listing (for getOwnPropertyNames at least) isn't exposed to the API.

Contextify: https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify
My fork: https://github.com/Benvie/contextify
Pull request: https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/pull/23

The second method will work universally but doesn't actually result in a proxy global. Essentially you create proxies for each existing object in global and then load the desired code inside a function created that shadows all the properties as function parameters. Something like:

```
var globals = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(global);
var proxies = globals.map(function(key){
  return forwardingProxy(global[key]);
});
globals.push(codeToRun);
var compiled = Function.apply(null, globals);
var returnValue = compiled.apply(forwardingProxy(global), proxies);
```

Comment: I'm taking a look at contextify, thanks !
About your second solution, how am I able to call `foo('bar')` without having to declare `foo` before?

Comment: Actually one way you can do it is particularly awesome and evil. `global.__proto__ = yourproxy` or `Window.prototype.__proto__ = yourproxy`. That serves to catch anything otherwise not declared globally, and the method I mentioned above to shadow everything that is declared covers the rest.

Comment: I get a `ReferenceError: foo is not defined` when trying with `foo('bar')`, and a `TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'foo'` when trying with `global.foo()`. Do you have any example of working implementation of the method you describe?

Comment: It helps tremendously to use a library which provides a forwarding handler so that stuff just gets forwarded unless you choose to intercept it. Using the library I made (https://github.com/Benvie/meta-objects) I did the following in Chrome: `Window.prototype.__proto__ = meta.proxy(Window.prototype.__proto__, meta.proxy({}, {get: function(f,t,trap){ return function(fwd,target,key){ typeof key === 'string' ? console.log(trap, key) : console.log(trap); return fwd() } } }))` (https://gist.github.com/2924338)

Comment: Is there any equivalent for NodeJS? Your library throws an error when required via `require()`.

Comment: check the additional answer I added below

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Don't even think of it. :)

Longer answer: There is a lot of magic involved in V8's treatment of the global object, in order to deal with browser issues like frames, security access checks, etc. As it stands, that magic is completely incompatible with using a proxy in its place. This may change eventually, but not any time soon.

Having said that, I also don't think you *should* do that. The global object is a terribly hacky feature, it is going to be demoted in Harmony, and you are best advised not to try playing dirty tricks with it.

Comment: Aw :C My dreams are being shattered. Proxies are not that magical after all.
Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
global.__proto__ = forwarder(global.__proto__);
console.log([hello, my, name, is, bob, weeeee])

function forwarder(target){
  var traps = {
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor.bind(null, target),
    getOwnPropertyNames: Object.getOwnPropertyNames.bind(null, target),
    keys: Object.keys.bind(null, target),
    defineProperty: Object.defineProperty.bind(null, target),
    get: function(r,k){ return target[k] },
    set: function(r,k,v){ target[k] = v; return true },
    has: function(k){ return k in target },
    hasOwn: function(k){ return {}.hasOwnProperty.call(target, k) },
    delete: function(k){ delete target[k]; return true },
    enumerate: function(){ var i=0,k=[]; for (k[i++] in target); return k }
  };

  var names = {
    get: 1,
    set: 1,
    has: 0,
    hasOwn: 0,
    delete: 0,
    defineProperty: 0,
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor: 0
  }

  return Proxy.create(Proxy.create({
    get: function(r, trap){
      return function(a, b){
        if (trap in names)
          console.log(trap, arguments[names[trap]])
        else
          console.log(trap);

        if (trap === 'get' && !target[b]);
          return b;

        if (trap in traps)
          return traps[trap].apply(target, arguments);
      }
    }
  }), Object.getPrototypeOf(target));
}
```

Comment: Throws `ReferenceError: hello is not defined`. Is it even possible to alter the global prototype? Does it work for you?

Comment: It might be because I'm using a newer version of Node. V8 prior to 3.8 has a number of significant bugs with the proxy implementation, which affects Node 0.6.x. You need to be using Node 0.7.x (soon to be 0.8) to use Proxies pretty much.

Comment: That was totally that. With nodejs 0.6.19, `global.__proto__ = proxy` won't work, but with 0.7.x, `global.__proto__ = proxy` does work. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: No problem! There was a few bugs related to issues with property lookups on proxies and especially proxies-as-[[prototype]] that were resolved. Note that there was one other one only recently resolved in V8 3.11 which isn't going to be in Node 0.8. That is, `set` always has the proxy as the receiver, even when it originated at something inheriting from the proxy. https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect/issues/4

Comment: [Sorry to revive, just rediscovered the question.] Although your suggestion might work in many cases, I still advise against it. As I mentioned in my reply, there is a lot of special handling of the global object (and its prototype chain) in V8, and it generally is not proxy-ready. You are on your own.